# Is there a way to use twig in my css?

Tags: symfony, twig

I would like to use the twig syntaxe in my css. The only way I found around was to create a .html file with the style tag.

Here's a concrete example of what I want to do :

```
// style.css.twig
#buttonAddToCart {
    color: {{ swatch.swatchColors.buttonAddToCart }};
}
```

I pretty sure this is possible because [in the symfony documenation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#template-suffix) it shows that css can have the twig extension.

---

EDIT: 
My base.html.twig :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>{{ shop.getShopTitleSh}}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('bundles/templateengine/legacy/css/style.css.twig') }}">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" >
        {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
        {% block metadata %}{% endblock %}
    <head>
    <body> /* ... */
```

Comment: it's not working, it just straight up output it as raw text. What I wrote is what is actually being output in my .css file

Comment: you should name your file style.css.twig. did you?

Comment: Yes I did it. I just use {{ asset( my_asset ) }}

Comment: paste whole code of template you're using

Comment: Here, I put my base.html.twig head is that what you needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include your style.css.twig file like:

```
<style>
    {% include 'YourBundle:style.css.twig' %}
</style>
```